# Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. - Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test the onClick but they are not being called using props:

here is part of the file.js

```
    handleSystemClick = () => {
// var message = All unsaved changes will be lost.`
confirmAlert({
  title: 'Confirm Navigation',
  message: ' All unsaved changes will be lost.',
  childrenElement: () => <div></div>,
  confirmLabel: 'Confirm',
  cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
  onConfirm: () => {this.setState({ toSystemEntitlments: true})},
  onCancel: () => {},
})

  }
 handleCancelClick = () => {
  window.history.back();
}
```

here is render method of file.js

```
render()
return(
<div className='add-edit-button' id= 'test1' onClick={() => {this.handleSystemClick()}}>System</div>
<div className='add-edit-button' onClick={() => {this.handleCancelClick()}}>Cancel</div>
<div className='add-edit-button' onClick={() => {this.handleSave()}}>Save</div>
      </div>
```

I have seen some examples here on stackoverflow and I tried to apply the following:

```
 // jest mock functions (mocks this.props.func)

 // defining this.props
   const baseProps = { 

   describe(' FunctionalEntitlement  Test', () => {
   let wrapper;
   let tree;

    beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(<BrowserRouter><Component     {...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>));


 it("should call handlesave function on button click", () => {
// Reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
baseProps.handleSave.mockClear();
wrapper.setProps({
});
wrapper.setState({ getINITIAL_STATE:""
});
wrapper.find('.add-edit-button').at(0).simulate("click");
  expect(baseProps.handleSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

});

Also How could I apply the same method for the first 2 clicks based on file.js

Thank you for the help

Comment: As far as I can see, the error looks like is when you find the edit button on the test, you're missing a dot to specify that is a CSS class. `wrapper.find('.add-edit-button')`

Comment: Martin - I already did that as well. it does not work.

Comment: Ok, when you `shallow` a component it will not render the children, in your case because your component is inside a `<BrowserRouter>` the `.add-edit-button` is not accessible. Try to `shallow` the component directly or use `mount` instead.

Comment: @MartinPrins I have done some unit testing in the past and  I was able to test a click inside  of a  <BrowserRouter>. I will try again based on your answer

Comment: Martin how could I improve based on your answer? I was able to pass using mount and wrote the following as an answer

Comment: I never seen as a function. Maybe I will apply into my test. Could you look at my answer ? how could I improve it. ?  thanks

Comment: @MartinPrins could you check this one out as well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889810/error-reactwrapperstateisopen-requires-that-state-not-be-null-or-un

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `shallow` there is a way to get the shallow wrapper of one of the children [using the `dive` method](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html). If you have to wrap your components with `BrowserRouter` frequently on the test, maybe it's worth it to have a helper method for this like:

```
function shallowWithBrowserRouter(component) {
   return shallow(<BrowserRouter>{component}</BrowserRouter>).childAt(0).dive();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to work something out but how could I improve the following answer.

Switched shallow to Mount in order to render children components

```
  it("should  call  button click 3 times", () => {
// Reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
 wrapper.setProps({
});
wrapper.setState({ 
});
wrapper.find('.add-edit-button').at(0).simulate("click");
wrapper.find('.add-edit-button').at(1).simulate("click");
wrapper.find('.add-edit-button').at(2).simulate("click");

expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
```

Comment: This would be more helpful if you showed the entire test.